# Does anyone know how to change the mouse behavior in Gnome Boxes?

Tags: mouse, virtualization, gnome-boxes

I have two mouse cursors in Gnome Boxes running Android and the mouse cursor does not "grab" like I think it should.

Instead, I have to click and drag to move the mouse cursor which is awful behavior for a touch screen interface like android because half of the time the screen moves with the mouse.

Does anyone know how to set the mouse pointer behavior in Gnome Boxes or the "grab" behavior of the mouse?

Thanks!

Comment: Sucks nobody answered this, having the same issue... Did you ever find a solution? Will post an answer if I find one.

Comment: @thebunnyrules I still have not found a solution. Thanks.

Comment: Seems to only occur android boxes. No such issues on other ISOs I tested... Had we been running qemu-kvm we could have just messed around with the switches but gnome-boxes doesn't really let you do that from what I could tell.

Comment: @thebunnyrules Yes, I only have this problem using android.

Comment: Looks like this problem only occurs on pre-existing images. I noticed that running android for the first time does not have this problem, it's only when I revert to a saved state or load a machine that I've previously setup that this problem takes place. Going to try installing grub and play around with -nomodeset and acpi=off

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that this craziness is happening because Android x86 (assuming that's what you're using) is a niche OS and it doesn't have SPICE plugins available. That's like Virtualbox additions for SPICE (SPICE is the display protocol that Gnome Boxes is using).

I've noticed that when running Android x86 in Gnome-Box for the first time, the emulated mouse deviates a little from the host mouse but syncs almost perfectly. When turning off the box or restoring a snapshot, it tends no longer sync the host and box mouse.

Re-installing Android x86 with Grub fixed the mouse sync problem for me. Something to do with starting the box in a text environment instead of Android's graphical environment seems to have done the trick.

I would recommend making a new box and testing it before you delete your old one -- in case it does not work for you.

Turn off the box using Android x86 tty screen instead of doing force shutdown and don't do any snapshots while it's on.

To turn off using tty:

Press Alt-Left
Enter: poweroff
Press Enter

Comment: Thanks for trying to figure this out. I still have the grab problem. I have to hold down the left click mouse button to move the cursor which moves the screen like a swipe. This makes menus hard to navigate so I have to use the tab key instead. I have tried using the tty to shut down and I tried using grub and I still get the same behavior. I will try and download the newest version of x86 to see if that does the trick. Thanks +1!

Comment: I got it working. Thanks! I installed the newest version 8.1-rc2 and this works. Before I was using 8.1-rc1.

Comment: Perfect. I just notice that the link I gave you was for a host app, no guest.